# Failing to find lcrypto on Mac OSX 10.14 when building syslog-ng

Tags: makefile, openssl, clang, syslog-ng

I'm building syslog-ng fro source as per the [guide here](https://syslog-ng.gitbooks.io/getting-started/content/chapters/chapter_0/section_3.html). However the build is failing to find the lcrypto library"

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make --no-print-directory all-recursive
  CCLD     modules/snmp-dest/libsnmpdest.la
  CCLD     modules/stardate/libstardate.la
  CCLD     modules/syslogformat/libsyslogformat.la
  CCLD     modules/system-source/libsystem-source.la
ld: library not found for -lcrypto.35
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [modules/snmp-dest/libsnmpdest.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think this is part of the OpenSSL library which I have installed?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the SNMP module? (`./configure --disable-snmp-dest ...`)

Answer (score 1):

`libcrypto` belongs to OpenSSL.
An important step in the syslog-ng compilation guide is that you have to install OpenSSL using `brew` and set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` accordingly before configuring and building the project, for example:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

Please note that currently (v3.22.1) syslog-ng is not tested/supported on macOS. Only compilation, unit tests and a few drivers are verified (manually), but for example, there is no native `system()` source.

If you want to experiment with syslog-ng on macOS, you can ask questions or share your feedback:

- [syslog-ng on GitHub](https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng)
- [syslog-ng Community contact channels](https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng#community)